# What is the value of $~\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1\frac{1+nx^2}{(1+x^2)^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I have been away from Real Analysis for a little while and have gotten rusty. I would like to ask if someone could verify my argument, or tell me what I'm doing wrong.

The question I have asks to find
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1\frac{1+nx^2}{(1+x^2)^n}$$
I claim it goes to $0$, here's my proof.

$\textbf{Proof:}$

Note that
$$\frac{1+nx^2}{(1+x^2)^n}=\frac{1+nx^2}{1+nx^2+\sum_{k=2}^n\binom{n}{k}x^{2k}}\text{ }(*)$$
for $n\geq 3$. As $x\geq0$, the above is bounded above by $1$, which is in $L^1(0,1)$, so by dominated convergence, assuming the integrand has a pointwise a.e. limit we have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1\frac{1+nx^2}{(1+x^2)^n}=\int_0^1\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1+nx^2}{(1+x^2)^n}\text{ }(**)$$
By $(*)$ we see that for $n\geq 3$ we have
$$0\leq\frac{1+nx^2}{(1+x^2)^n}\leq\frac{1+nx^2}{(1+nx^2+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}x^4)}$$

Letting $n\to\infty$ the R.H.S. of the above tends to $0$, hence for a.e. $x$ by squeezing
$$\frac{1+nx^2}{(1+x^2)^n}\to 0$$
as $n\to\infty$, therefore by $(**)$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1\frac{1+nx^2}{(1+x^2)^n}=\int_0^10=0$$
This completes the proof. $\blacksquare$

Comment: Looks good to me! You don't look rusty, get a tougher one for yourself.

Comment: The solution looks sound. There's a typo in the denominator on the rightmost term in the inequality, that should be $\frac{n(n-1)}2x^4$.

Comment: @Fawkes4494d3 Thank you, corrected it.

Comment: @астон вілла тереса лисбон Thank you. I plan to.

Comment: @subhajit I used Dominated Convergence to switch the limit and integral. No need for uniform continuity.